# Чтение .tab файла в golang

Tags: golang

мне нужно прочитать файл с расширение (.tab)
во мой код по которому я пытался это сделать, но он выводит лишь пустое значение

```
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text(), " ////scanner")
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы бы хоть намекнули, какой именно формат у ваших `.tab` файлов. Расширения не прибиты гвоздями к форматам, и всякое бывает.

Тем не менее рискну предположить, что у вас файл со значениями, разделёнными знаками табуляции.

Тогда вам поможет пакет `encodings/csv`. Не смотрите, что в названии пакета фигурирует `csv`, он умеет читать не только файлы с запятыми. Достаточно сказать ему, что запятая - это табуляция, как он начнет читать файлы с табуляциями.

```
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("test.tab")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    r := csv.NewReader(f)
    r.Comma = '\t' // Запятой считать табуляцию
    records, err := r.ReadAll() // прочитать всё содержимое файла за один раз
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // распечатать построчно
    for lnum, line := range records {
        fmt.Print("Line #", lnum, ":")
        for _, x := range line {
            fmt.Print("|", x)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Тестовый файл `test.tab` был таким:

```
11  12  13
21  22  23
31  32  33
```

Результат работы программы:

```
Line #0:|11|12|13
Line #1:|21|22|23
Line #2:|31|32|33
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! содержимое файла это

```
sdssfef|fdgdrgrg|dfvfdvve
vevrvrv||cdcdcsdc
dcsddscds||

Comment: @АНЕЛяХ тогда вам нужно в строке `r.Comma = '\t'` написать `r.Comma = '|'`